# What databases are needed for IdentityServer4 AD provider

Tags: identityserver4

Currently I have a working IdentityServer4 service that allows users to authenticate to active directory only.  They authenticate and then they have no issue accessing the api.  I'm using the the IDP server from [IdentityServer4 Quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer) with all the local user account stuff stripped out. Here is my database:

[image]

My question is this, were are tokens stored?  Only in the browser?  Am I doing something wrong?  Should there be some sort of database that holds tokens for SSO?  It is working but I'm worried I'm missing out on some sort of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PersistedGrants table stores the following type of tokens: authorization_code, refresh_token, reference_token, and user_consent.

Regular id_tokens and access_tokens are not persisted in the database, they will be passed to the client to be handled as it sees fit.

SSO is achieved when your IDP server creates a cookie contain identity and session information for your browser to reuse.